# How to resolve Access denied (1045) error when creating tenant in tenancyforlaravel package

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, multi-tenant, laravel-9

I have a laravel 9 project, that I am trying to make multi-tenant. I am using the tenancyforlaravel.com package It gives me the following error, but when I check  in the the db server the database is created.But it is created with a new user, not the root user.

What could be the problem?

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'MAHcx42oEpVhqADN'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = school_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE').
```

I am using MacOS and phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Did you try logging into MySQL with the username and password provided in your question ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to login onto phpMyAdmin with the root username and password. But when I use Tinker to create a tenant it gives the above error

Comment: I mean did you try with the user that you have called MAHcx42oEpVhqADN ?

Comment: No I did not try with that user

Comment: you may need to check the database server itself to make sure that the user 'MAHcx42oEpVhqADN'@'localhost' has the correct permissions to access the database. If this user was created by the tenancyforlaravel package, you may need to modify the permissions for this user on the database server to allow it to connect to the database.